# Method in protocol don't work properly

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

I don't understand why this code work properly for example in

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITabBarItem *item1 = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

    visibleMapRect = self.mappa.visibleMapRect;
    visibleAnnotations = [mappa annotationsInMapRect:visibleMapRect];

    if(visibleAnnotations.count>0){
        item1.enabled=true;
    }
    else{
        item1.enabled=false;

    }

}
```

but don't work if I put it into a method called by protocol/delegate (locale)

The protocol system is working good because the `NSLog` is showed in consolle

```
-(void)locale{

    UITabBarItem *item1 = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

    visibleMapRect = self.mappa.visibleMapRect;
    visibleAnnotations = [mappa annotationsInMapRect:visibleMapRect];

    if(visibleAnnotations.count>0){
        item1.enabled=true;
     }
     else{
         item1.enabled=false;

     }

     NSLog(@"%d",visibleAnnotations.count);


 }
```

In first method `NSLog(@"%d",visibleAnnotations.count);` return the correct number... but in the protocol method it return always 0 ;

Comment: Why tag this with `xcode`?

Comment: That sort of belies a misunderstanding of what Xcode *is*.

Comment: @userXXXX wouldn't this question be the same if you used `emacs` and `make`, really?

Comment: sorry I don't understand the problem

Comment: @user1639377, Xcode is an editor, the same as emacs, textmate, etc (but with more bells and whistles) your question is about Objective-C and/or the iOS SDK... it is agnostic of the fact that you're using Xcode as your IDE.

Comment: ok but I have insert x code ad first tag!

Comment: If you needed help solving a math problem, would you tag it with “pencil”?  That's what you're doing when you tag this with “xcode”.

Comment: @user1639377 No, please don't, for the reasons we just described.

Comment: To get back on topic: what class contains these methods?  How is the `locale` method getting called?

Comment: ok the problem is that I don't understand english very well sorry :( can you help me about the problem?

Comment: Try putting `NSLog(@"Mappa: %@", mappa);` inside `locale` to see what your object is.

Comment: uhm Mappa=nil... this is the problem.. but there is not reason!

Comment: When is this `locale` method being called? Might it be before `self.mappa` is first assigned?